# Find the expected number of edges in the graph.

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory

It is given that we have a graph with n nodes labelled $\left\{1,2,...,n \right\} $. For each pair of nodes $\left(i\neq j\right)$ , A fair coin is tossed to decide if there should be an edge $\left(i\leftrightarrow j\right)$.

Q1). If we define a random variable E that counts the number of
edges in the resulting random graph, what distribution would E follow?

Q2). What is the expected number of edges in the resulting graph?

I have no idea of what to do in the 1st question. Here is my work for the second part:

I arranged the node in the increasing order and then we start by tossing coin for node 1. Since there are $n-1$ edges other than node 1, we will have $(n-1)$ tosses for this edge. Similarly for the node 2, we will have $(n-2)$
tosses and so on till the node $(n-1)$ will have only one toss and 0 tosses for node $n$ since n has been paired with all the preceding edges for the toss. Since each toss presents a $(1/2)$ probability that the edge will be drawn, Expected number of edges(I am taking the edges as direction-less.) will be $\left(1/2\right)\left\{ 0 + 1 +2 + ...(n-1)\right\} $ = $n(n-1)/4$.

Can you verify my calculations? ALso can you help me with the first part because I am clueless about it.

Comment: Your calculation is correct. For the first question: note that the problem is equivalent to asking for the distribution of the number of heads when you toss a fair coin $\binom{n}2=\frac12n(n-1)$ times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting distribution will be [binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution),

$$p(\text{number of edges}=r)=\binom{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}{r}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$$

As far as the expected value is concerned your answer is correct. $$\text{mean}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{4}$$

Comment: Thanks! :) This helped a lot!